# How to find out whether user accepted startLockTask

Tags: android, locking, lockscreen

I want to allow users to lock the device in a sports activities tracking app, to avoid unintentionally leaving the app while exercising.

Therefore I provide a button which locks the input controls of my app and in addition provides the option to lock also the home and overview button, by calling Activity.startLockTask().

I know, that I can call ActivityManager.getLockTaskModeState() later on to find out, whether the user accepted the lock or not.

But what is the best time to do that, or in other words, is there a reliable event that is called, when the popup provided by the system is accepted or rejected by the user?

I checked already that onResume of my activity is not called.

I also found DeviceAdminReceiver.onLockTaskModeEntering/Exiting. But this is meant for administrated devices only and I don't think it can be used without a lot of additional hassle (if possible at all).

I also hoped that the view, which is temporarily hidden by the system popup, gets any of its onWindowFocusChanged, onWindowVisibilityChanges or any other "onWhateverChanged" methods called. But no breakpoint was hit in the methods I tried to overwrite.